# Sequence of Navigation path for a website in a GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am working on a website having Google Analytics 4 setup on it. I want to understand the sequence users usually take while navigating from different pages in website. for example

```
home page    \            1
career       \career      3
resource     \resource    2
```

In below case the particular user visit homepage then resource and then career. I want to know the navigation of sequence of users. Is there any predefined dimensions which i can refer to generate  this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a multi step funnel.  Start at the home page and then add the subsequent pages as steps in your funnel.

The funnel creation tool can be accessed by clicking on explore on the left hand column menu.  Click funnel exploration option.  In the steps section, set each page visit as a step.